# What is the difference between $x \in x$ and $x=x$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was looking at the proof of Russell's paradox that used the property $x \notin x$, and at the proof that the empty set exists using the property $x ≠  x$, for any set $x$.

My question is: What is the difference in the implication whether $x$ is an element of $x$ and whether $x$ is equal to $x$?

- Does $x \in x$ imply $x=x$?
- Does $x=x$ imply $x \in x$?

Comment: No. They have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: then what is the difference between the two of them? Because to me they seem to imply the same thing.

Comment: Hard to answer without knowing what you think is the same about them. What is the "same thing" they both seem to imply?

Comment: $x=x$ is always true. $x\in x$ is never (or hardly ever) true. Can't get much more different than that.

Comment: $1\in\{1,2,3\}$ but $1\neq \{1,2,3\}$.

Comment: I think that saying set x is an element of set x is the same as saying x is equals to itself, similarly if x is equals to itself, then x is an element of x.

Comment: Is $\{1,2,3\}\in\{1,2,3\}$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  {1,2,3} ∈ {1,2,3}? I think so, is it right?

Comment: Is saying "Joe is himself" the same as saying "Joe shaves himself"?

Comment: @bof why is x∈x never (or hardly ever) true?

Comment: @g.s this notation " x∈x" came from Russell's paradox that i was looking at.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox

Comment: @jenny0415 Do you see a difference between $x \in y$ and $x = y$?

Comment: It's hard to understand what you think either of the statements mean, as they are obviously completely different.  I can not understand why you think *anything* you've said is reasonable. $a=b$ means $a$ and $b$ are the same thing.  $5=2+3$ because they are the same thing.  $a\in b$ means $b$ is a set and $a$ is a member of the set. drangonfly={insects}.  x=x means x is the same thing as itself. That is always true. {insects}={insects}. x$\in$x means $x$ is a set and $x$ is the member of the set. {insects}$\in${insects} means the set of all insects is itself an insect. Completely different.

Comment: Oh. I see. You are confusing "being a subset of" with "being an element of".  Very different ideas. If x is a set then $x\subset x$ is always true. So is $x=x$. It's impossible for them to not both be true. It may be true that $x\in x$, for example The Set of All Sets that Can be Described in Twelve Words$\in$The Set of All Sets that Can be Described in Twelve Words.  But it might not be. {chocolate cakes}$\not\in${chocolate cakes} because {chocolate cakes} is not *itself* a chocolate cake. So $x=x\not\implies x\in x$.

Comment: On the other hand EVERYTHING $\implies x=x$.  My dog eats dog food$\implies x=x$.  Penguins are martians$\implies x=x$.  $x\ne x\implies x=x$.  EVERYTHING$\implies x=x$ because $x=x$ is always true.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: I think you are confusing $x\in x$ with $x\subset x$.  The first means "element of" or "is a", and the second means "is contained by" or "everything in the first set is also an element of the second set."  For instance, $\text{Fido}\in\text{Dogs}$ but it is not true that $\text{Dogs}\in\text{Dogs}$, but it is is definitely true that $\text{Dogs}\subset \text{Dogs}$ (or $\text{Dogs}\subseteq\text{Dogs}$ if you insist $\subset$ means proper subset).

(Trivia: the "$\in$" symbol is a stylized lunate epsilon $\varepsilon$, a Greek letter.  It was a mathematical shorthand for writing the Latin word "est", which means "is", and used in the sense of "is a".  In math textbooks from around the 1940's, you can see $x\ \varepsilon\ X$ instead of the modern $x\in X$.)

---

The relationship between equality and element-of is this: $X=Y$ means the same thing as $X\subset Y$ and $Y\subset X$, where $A\subset B$ is defined to be "for all $a\in A$, $a\in B$, too."  Shortened: two sets are equal if they have exactly the same elements.

It is true that $x\in x$ implies $x=x$, but that is because $x=x$ is a tautology.

If $x=x$, it is not necesarily the case that $x\in x$.  For instance, if $x=\{\}$, then $x\not\in x$ (since the empty set has no elements, and in particular, not $x$).  However, there is an axiom of set theory called the Axiom of Foundation mathematicians have adopted that makes it so we can assume $x\in x$ is false, no matter what $x$ is.  (I have heard about people studying what happens when sets can contain themselves as elements.)

---

While modern set theory uses the Axiom of Foundation, Russell's paradox makes no use of it (this is why it is OK for the paradox to use $x\not\in x$ even though the Axiom of Foundation implies this is true no matter the $x$).  It illustrates how Frege's Axiom of Extensionality (that every predicate can be realized as a set) leads to logical inconsistency.  The fix to this is the Axiom of Separation, that predicates can only be used to construct subsets.

Comment: Thank you! I would like to clarify: in the proof for existence for empty set, the property "x ≠ x" is used instead of x∉x. Hence while your explanation for x∉x for empty set makes sense, what is the intuition of using "x ≠ x" instead?

Comment: You can use any false property.  For instance, given the fact $A$ is a set, the following is the empty set: $\{x\in A:1+1=3\}$.  This uses the Axiom of Separation to take the set of all things from $A$ where false is true.  This leaves nothing.

Answer (score 1):

It is perfectly valid for a set to contain some set as an element of it. In Russell's paradox, we are temporarily considering the possibility of a set containing all sets that do not contain themselves as elements. Another way of saying this is we are considering the possibility of a set of all solutions to the formula $x \notin x$, *where x ranges over all sets*. (One of the takeaways of Russel's paradox is that this is a bad thing to do.) So, when one asserts that $x \in x$, we are saying that $x$ is a set that contains itself as an element. The result of Russell's paradox is that if $x =${all S such that S is a set that does not contain itself }, then $x \in x \iff x \notin x$.